# Set default Magento page layout to 3 columns

Tags: magento

Is there a way to set all pages (catalog,product,cart,checkout,search) as having a 3-column layout in local.xml, instead of specifying layout for each block?

I tried the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
        <default>
                <reference name="root">
                        <action method="setTemplate"><template>3columns.phtml</template></action>
                </reference>
        </default>
</layout>
```

It's not working; the log shows

> 2011-08-12T07:20:10+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template
> file:frontend\base\default\template\3columns.phtml

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as your error message is concerned, you are trying to load a file that doesn't exist.  The filename in the error message was a *huge* giveaway.  The page layout files are in `template/page/*.phtml`, not `template/*.phtml`.

You need to change:

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>3columns.phtml</template></action>
```

to..

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should override **page.xml** layout and change the *root* block template in the *default handle*.

Copy **app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml**
to **app/design/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/layout/page.xml**

Do the appropriate changes there :

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
        <!-- ... -->
    </block>
</default>
```

Comment: It is far more upgrade-safe to do all the XML changes in a custom local.xml. If you do so, you do not have to copy any layout files at all...